# Check radio button when input changes

Tags: angularjs

[Sign in image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wMQHS.png)

What do I put in the controller to select the 'Yes' option button when a user starts typing in the password field?

```
<!-- views/index.html -->

<label for="optionsRadios1">
  <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios1" value="new" ng-model="user.type" checked>
  No, I am a <b>new customer</b>.
</label>

<label>
  <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios2" value="old" ng-model="user.type">
  Yes, I have a password:
  <input id="password" ng-change="changeupinhere()" ng-model="password2014" type="password" name="password">
</label>
```

## Controller

```
   $scope.changeupinhere = function () {
      // What do I put here?
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$scope.changeupinhere = function () {
  $scope.user.type = 'old';
};
```